# Why Application.LocalUserAppDataPath throwing InvalidDeploymentException "Application identity is not set."

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple program here that demonstrate the problem i am having. I have a library i am trying to use which is .net and develop for x86/32bit. Now my window in 64bit and visual studio was give error in debuging that that image format is not right so i changed the build target to x86. Now i am getting another error which occure when `LocalUserAppDataPath` is accessed.

```
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Console.WriteLine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this. If I run it without debugger it work ok but within visual studio debugger it give exception.

Answer (score 0):

Tracing through the framework using Reflector:

```
public static string LocalUserAppDataPath
{
   get
   {
      ...
      if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
```

which calls:

```
public static bool IsNetworkDeployed
{
   get
   {
      ...
      ApplicationDeployment currentDeployment = CurrentDeployment;
```

which calls:

```
public static ApplicationDeployment CurrentDeployment
{
   ...
   get
   {
      ActivationContext activationContext = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ActivationContext;
      ...
      fullName = activationContext.Identity.FullName;

      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName))
      {
         throw new InvalidDeploymentException(Resources.GetString("Ex_AppIdNotSet"));
      }
```

So check if `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ActivationContext` is assigned.

And if it is, check that `.Identity.Fullname` is something.

Comment: The problem here is the way IsNetworkDeployed property was implemented. It uses exceptions to control the workflow. Basically, if you see that exception in the Output window it means the application is not network deployed.

You shouldn't worry about this annoying exception if you're not doing ClickOnce deployment.